# Is there Function (VB6 or Excel) for convert json date to date format

Tags: excel-formula

have a good day

i need to create DataBase for exchange rate USD from highcharts

[this is json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsEO9.jpg)

i success to extract this file "usd.json" to excel sheet

but the problem how can i convert the column A to Date format

is this possible

[this is excel sheet picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUmo8.jpg)

thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

[image]
C1 ↓

```
=TEXT(A1/86400000+DATE(1970,1,1),"mm-dd-e")
```

Or.  A1 ↓
[image]

```
=TEXT(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(WEBSERVICE("https://sp-today.com/past/currency/damascus/usd.json"),"[",),"]",),",","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&ROW(A1)*2-1&"]")/86400000+DATE(1970,1,1),"mm-dd-e")
```

English is not my native language，I am a little hard to understand what you mean, sorry. please excuse typing errors.

Comment: thank you for reply 
but the formula didn't work correct 
the column A is Date!!!!
you can enter this address (https://sp-today.com/past/currency/damascus/usd.json)

Comment: @ammarbakkar I have updated the reply, I hope useful.